# How to perform this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have these 2 tables, proc and users. I am creating a web site where users can post proclomations and people can make a search and find them according the search criteria. I want to display users' profile picture next to their proclomations. Rest of the data are in the same table so I only have problem with pp.

I get the syntax error when I try to run this query.

Users table:

---

### | ID | username| usersurname| image | email | countryCode | mobile | pwd |

Proc table

---

### proc_id | p_name | p_surname |uid | p_from | p_where | etc. (rest is not relevant)

I've tried this on phpmyadmin:

```sql
SELECT * FROM proc WHERE p_from = 'Baku' UNION
SELECT users.image FROM users INNER JOIN ON proc WHERE proc.uid = users.id
```

But it doesn't work.

This is how I was displaying results before. Now I also want to select pp from image column from users table

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proc WHERE p_from = '".$from."' and p_where = '".$where."' and type= '".$type."' and p_date >= '".$procDate."'
ORDER BY p_date, price LIMIT " . $page_first_result . " , " . $results_per_page . "";
```

Comment: What mean doesnt work? error? wrong result?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, sorry. Updated the question. I get the syntax error when I try to run it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This looks like PHP code attempting to build a SQL string? Then you claim it fails in phpMyAdmin (which is a GUI tool). So presumably you copied and pasted the output of the PHP script into phpMyAdmin to run it? In that case, what was the final output  which failed to execute? Did you `echo $sql;` and copy that output? What did it look like? If you want us to fix a SQL syntax error you'd have to show us the finished SQL. And also telling us the exact error message would help

Comment: I can see you are building the query using string concatenation. Knowing nothing of PHP and PHPMyAdmin, I'd say that your problem is most likely there. Let's say that one of your parameters ($where, for example) contains a single quote: your query will break. There are better ways to pass parameters to a query: I strongly recommend switching to one of those methods as your method is subject to SQL Injection (and, of course, impossibility to run queries with certain parameter values).

Comment: P.S. the first example above, where you have several SELECT statements, looks fairly obviously wrong tbh. a) in MySQL, such statements would need to be separated by a `;`. b) in PHP, most of the common code libraries will not let you execute multiple statements at once, unless you specifically run a `multi_select()` method (or similar, according to your chosen library). So maybe that's the source of your issue. Since you didn't actually tell us the full error or show us the final SQL, it's hard to be sure of anything. Help us to help you by explaining things fully.

Comment: @ADyson I've run that SQL code in phpmyadmin which I stated belove I've tried section. It gives me this: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON proc WHERE proc.uid = users.id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

Of course I didn't include tha php variables. I run it like this: SELECT * FROM proc WHERE p_where  = 'Baku' UNION ......

Comment: @FilippoPossenti yes I am aware of that weaknesses but I will fix them later on after trimming these minor issues.

Comment: _" I've run that SQL code in phpmyadmin which I stated belove I've tried section"_ ...what you showed in the "I've tried" section still isn't valid SQL, it's a mixture of PHP and SQL. So we still can't see what you actually executed, because we don't know what's in all those `$xyz` variables. But...`ON proc` doesn't look like valid syntax. If that's part of a JOIN clause it should be something like `ON proc.someField = someOtherTable.someOtherField`. Hard to see how the query you showed would end up with that in it, anyway?? There are no joins in your query.

Comment: @ADyson yes that definiton is not corect I understand. But I mentioned in my previous comment that I didn't use that php variables in phpmyadmin. Anyways, thank you for your effort and trying to understand the problem, I got what I needed belove

Comment: "I mentioned in my previous comment that I didn't use that php variables in phpmyadmin." Ok but then a) why did you show it and b) why didn't you show what you **did** use?? Someone has guessed it below, luckily, but in future if you want some specific code fixing then you really need to show the actual code, not the code which generates it, or some other code entirely. We couldn't see what was really happening, we could only guess. As it happens, someone guessed right, but you wouldn't want to rely on that

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  users.image, proc.*
FROM 
  users 
JOIN
  proc
ON
  proc.uid=users.id
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...
```

Please, **NEVER** write this: `p_from = '".$from."'`. I do mean, **NEVER**. Read up on this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp . Then **NEVER** write that again.

Comment: I've read it. To tell you the truth before starting this project I've never interracted with php. That's why most of the system is wide open to injection and many people told me that in my other quetions. So I've corrected myself and applied all those advises. I will apply your adivse as well. But I just wanted to make sure that backend works. Now I can fix the security. So don't worry I reall apretiate your comment and advise and I will definetly use it ;)